# Running commands in bash for puppetmaster

Tags: puppet

I tried the following in 2.7.11-1ubuntu2.3. And got the following error: 
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not match $(pecl at /etc/puppet/modules/php5/manifests/init.pp:90 on node xxxx.

Any idea how I can run commands?

## On client,

> puppet agent --test

## On master

```
    exec { "pecl_memcache" :
            provider => shell,
            command  => "if [ -n "$(pecl install memcache | egrep fail )" ]; then echo y | pecl install memcache-3.0.8; fi",
            logoutput => true,
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape those quotes and variables inside the command parameter; they are being evaluated by Puppet instead of by bash.

However, it is cleaner to use `onlyif` instead of relying on the shell to check output:

```
exec { "pecl_memcache" :
        provider  => shell,
        command   => "pecl install memcache-3.0.8",
        unless    => "pecl install memcache | egrep fail",
        logoutput => true,
}
```

The slight difference here is that `unless` relies on the exit code of egrep, whereas the -n test just looks for a non-empty string.  This should be functionally the same in this case.

Comment: It seems that the logic is incorrect. Ideally what I need is that if the "install fail" message shows, it means that the package was installed, therefore it should not run the command.

Comment: Change onlyif to unless.